# JasperReport Print Multiple Records in One Row

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using JasperReport and iReport.
I want to create a page that has 8 records per page, in 2x4 layout (col x row).
I'm using it using subreport and have each subreport to skip to next record accordingly, which I think is stupid and could be done in a better way. 
Anyone has experience before?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set the columns property for the report to 2. It will cut your available width in half, and it will automatically put the data into 2 columns.